# Unfortunately, "app name here" has stopped - followed tutorial

Tags: java, android

To begin with, I followed this tutorial:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/102065/Android-A-beginner-s-guide?fid=1583614&df=90&mpp=10&noise=1&prof=True&sort=Position&view=Expanded&spc=None&fr=11#xx0xx

I have checked a good many of the similar posts here, but all of the solutions have been code specific and haven't worked.

I am just starting out developing android apps, and found this tutorial.  When I launch it though, the emulator gives me the this app has stopped message.  There are no warnings from my code, so I don't even know where to begin.

Here's my code:
MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    //return true;

//get the two controls we created earlier, also with the resource reference and the id
final TextView lv_View = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lv_View);
lv_View.setText("4");
final EditText et_Text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_Text);  

//add new KeyListener Callback (to record key input)
et_Text.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
{
    //function to invoke when a key is pressed
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        //check if there is 
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            //check if the right key was pressed
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)
            {
                                //add the text to the text view
                lv_View.setText(lv_View.getText() + ", " + 
                                 et_Text.getText());
                                //and clear the EditText control
                et_Text.setText("");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
return true;
} 
}
```

test manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">test</string>
<string name="hello_world">&quot;I got it to work!&quot;</string>
<string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>

</resources>
```

activity_main.xml (layout)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
 >
 <edittext android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="#FF0000FF"
         android:id="@+id/et_Text" />
<textview android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:textColor="#FF00FF00" android:id="@+id/lv_View" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textColor="#FF00FF00"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" 
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat report

```
12-18 21:34:37.873: W/Trace(713): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-18 21:34:38.442: W/Trace(713): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-18 21:34:38.522: W/Trace(713): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-18 21:34:39.562: D/AndroidRuntime(713): Shutting down VM
12-18 21:34:39.602: W/dalvikvm(713): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0x40a70930)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}:     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class edittext
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class edittext
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  ... 11 more
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.edittext" on path: /data/app/com.example.test-2.apk
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:643)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  ... 21 more
```

Thanks for any help!  If you need any more information, just let me know.  I'm still not sure of what's needed to trouble shoot these kinds of errors.

Comment: I think it's because of the lowertext edittext. You should use EditText in your layout xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your layout XML file, you need to ensure that `textview` and `edittext` are CamelCase otherwise android will not know how to inflate the layout. This is because the android layout inflater attempts to instance a class by using the name specifed in the XML file. In this case, `android.view.TextView` and `android.view.EditText`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:textColor="#FF0000FF"
         android:id="@+id/et_Text" />

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:textColor="#FF00FF00"
         android:id="@+id/lv_View" />

    <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:textColor="#FF00FF00"
         android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Hollis Scriber You need to learn to understand logcat errors. The error was in the line : 12-18 21:34:39.812: E/AndroidRuntime(713): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}:     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class edittext

Comment: Even if I had seen that, I wouldn't have had any idea what it meant.  As soon as it lets me choose an answer, Tom Leese has it!  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You need to watch your spelling. Things like this are case **sensitive**.

```
edittext
```

should be

```
EditText
```

Same with the `textview` element directly below it.

It should be

```
TextView
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your log cat I would think that you are getting this error because `edittext` should be `EditText`, and the sane with `TextView`